# What does the '?src=sp' parameter do in the facebook sharer?

Tags: facebook, share

I use a simple sharer link for facebook:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http:...&t=title...

I have seen some links on other pages adding:

&src=sp

What does this extra parameter do? Is it necessary?